# Eclipse CDT could not find #include <__debug>

Tags: c++, eclipse, osx-yosemite

Everything was fine last week when I click the build button for a c++ project and it would generate the binary and I can run the program properly. But today after I updated the "Command Line Tools" in the app store(Btw my laptop is mac OSX 10.10.2), when I click the build button, it will generate this error message

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iterator:341:10: fatal error: '__debug' file not found
"#include <__debug>"

1 error generated.

And I can no longer generate the binaries and run my program...

I didn't change any of the settings in eclipse.

So how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I fixed this problem. Whoever got this problem today after you updated to CMDT 6.3 version. You can just download back the commandlinetoolsosx10.10forxcode6.2.dmg from Apples Developer Download Page. Everything will work fine as before.

Comment: This fixed my problem. I'm hosting the file at http://russellsstewart.com/s/commandlinetoolsosx10.10forxcode6.2.dmg if anyone wants it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue in my case downloading ["commandlinetoolsosx10.10forxcode6.3.2.dmg"](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) from apples webpage

Answer (score -1):

New Os does not allow to install the previous version of CommandLineToolsosx10.1